# Angular automatic module registration for global config service

Tags: angular, typescript, module, configuration

I work on an Angular 16 application with several resources modules with their own directory and routing. They are lazy, loaded. I want to create a pattern to register new modules configuration automatically and use a global config service for navigation or actions on these resources.

For example:

1. My new module A have its own configuration class with config elements.
2. I just past this new module without doing anything else.
3. My application register all modules configurations on start.
4. I have a global config service that contain all these module configuration's.
5. I can use these configurations everywhere in the app (e.g. navigation items, routes, etc.)

To achieve this, I tried to use an abstract config class that call a register method on the service:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
class ModuleAResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig { 
  // module A specific configs

  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

abstract class ResourceConfig {

  // sharedConfigElements

  constructor() {
     Inject(ResourceService).register(this);
  }
}

/** global service */
class ResourceService {

 resourceConfig: Record<ResourceConfigKey, ResourceConfig>
 ...

 register(config: ResourceConfig): void {
   // register the new config
 }
```

To register a configuration, I have to instantiate the specifics config classes. To-do this, I used providers with an InjectionToken in the app module:

```js
export const RESOURCE_CONFIG_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ResourceConfig[]>('resourceConfigToken');

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: RESOURCE_CONFIG_TOKEN,
      useClass: ModuleAResourceConfig,
      multi: true,
    },
    {
      provide: RESOURCE_CONFIG_TOKEN,
      useClass: ModuleBResourceConfig,
      multi: true,
    },
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

First, **I'm not sure if it's the best method to achieve my request** and I think it's not a good way. **It will be very cool if I could get rid of this AppModule modifications**. Have you ever experimented with this kind of architecture ?